# how to dismiss the dialogue and clear the username and password in android

Tags: android

Hi In My After clicking the login button username and password after loading I need to clear the username and password.
And login it's moving to next activity but,clicking emulator back button dialogue is showing with loading symbol.
can any one help me.

**login**

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "", 
                       "loading", true);  

             dialog.show();
               isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
               if (!isInternetPresent) {
                   showAlertDialog(Login.this, "No Internet Connection",
                           "You don't have internet connection.", true);

                   return;


               }
               String username = usname.getText().toString();
               String password = pword.getText().toString();

               String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);


                   if (username.equals("")) {
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER USERNAME",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }
                   if (password.equals("")) {
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER PASSWORD",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }

              else if (!CheckUsername(username) && !CheckPassword(password)){
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER VALID USERNAME & PASSWORD",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               else{
                   queryString = "username=" + username + "&password="
                            + password ;
                  String usertype = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("usertype",queryString);
                  System.out.print(usertype);

            if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin user Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));


            }
            else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Student User Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });

                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, StudentPortal.class);

                i.putExtra("username",username);

            startActivity(i);
            }

            else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("Teacher  user Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Sucess",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));
                finish();
            }
            else if(usertype.equalsIgnoreCase("No User Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        tv1.setText("InValid UserName and Password");


                    }

                });
                        }


            }

           }


         });

       tv1.setText("");

    }
```

Comment: call an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in `Button` click in [`onPreExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute()) show `Dialog`, in [`onPostExecute(Result)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) **dismiss that Dialog, Move to Next Activity and changes in UI** and in [`doInBackground(Params...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) all `Network` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

before starting new activity

Comment: try to call dialog.dismiss() inside the run() function

Comment: I think the connection may be very fast so that you can not notice the dialog. I would suggest using AsyncTask and show the dialog in the onPreExecute() and dismiss it in the onPostExecute().. If it is still not visible then the connection is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "",  
>                        "loading", true);   
>
>              dialog.show();
> ```

You're displaying progress dialog, and I dont see that you're dismissing it after any action / startActivity.

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: is it the dialog the one that keeps appearing or the navigation already flown to the next and when user clicks back the login activity is shown with the dialog??

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the dialog whereever you are calling the `startActivity` put the below code above 'startActivity'

> dialog.dismiss()

or you can make dissmiss by custom method.

Comment: If you can able to see the toast then Put the dismiss dialog line into runOnUi method where you have disply the Toast. You will be able to see or your response is too fast that it will display and dismiss speedily

Comment: ok then put dialog.dissmiss in runOnUiThread. it will dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

for not keeping the login activity in the stack and disallow the user to go back to it you should add this to your activity mapping: `LoginActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true">`

Answer (score 0):

It is best way if you used an [**`AsyncTask.`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

call an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in `Button` click in [`onPreExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute()) show `Dialog`, in [`onPostExecute(Result)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) **dismiss that Dialog, Move to Next Activity, make changes in UI and show Toast** and in [`doInBackground(Params...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) all `Network` call